# No guardar en cascada en Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Si tengo por ejemplo una clase *persona* y esta se relaciona con un *domicilio*, en una tabla aparte, uno a uno, entonces creo un objeto *persona*, le seteo su objeto *dirección* y al guardar con *Guardar cambios*, guarda el usuario y el *domicilio* **en cascada**.

Eso está bien y así debe ser, ahora bien, esta *persona* también tiene un perfil, a la persona le seteo un *perfil*, pero al guardar no quiero que genere un registro en la tabla *perfiles*, sino que solo guarde el `idperfil` en la tabla *personas*, es decir, que no guarde **en cascada**.

¿Cómo puedo setear o configurar la clase *persona* para que no guarde *en cascada*?

Hay algo que no entiendo, acá les paso el código de mi `insert`:

```
public Boolean insert()
{
    try
    {
        using (ModelSistema contexto = new ModelSistema())
        {
            MotivoFallecimiento a = this.toEntity();
            contexto.MotivosFallecimientos.Add(a);
            contexto.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

En la tabla *motivo de fallecimiento* tengo el `idUsuario` de quien cargo el *motivo de fallecimiento* en el sistema. Lo que sucede es que al guardar el *motivo de fallecimiento* guarda una tupla de usuario en la tabla usuarios, pero no debería, solo debería guardar el `idUsuario` en la tabla *motivos de fallecimiento* para que quede la relación.

Comment: Hola Lucho. Hay ciertas cosas que no son tan fáciles de entender con palabras solamente. Este es uno de esos casos. Sería conveniente que acompañes tu explicación con código que nos ayude a visualizar el contexto de tu pregunta.

Comment: Hola gracias x responder, es que creo que para mostrarlo tengo que poner mucho código, básicamente quiero que al guardar un objeto en entity Framework, no guarde ni inserte los objetos que tiene "dentro" , sino que solo guarde el id para que quede relacionado...

Comment: Te dejo un enlace útil para saber cómo compartir código que no sea demasiado largo, pero que tenga lo necesario para ayudar a contestar este tipo de preguntas: [mcve].

Comment: creo q ahi entendi como editar y escribir nuevas respuestas, ahora puse codigo para que se entienda mejor la pregunta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias analizar la asignacion del `State` de ese objeto

[Entity Framework Add and Attach and Entity States](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj592676(v=vs.113).aspx)

si se trata de un objeto desconectado usaras el `Attach()` y con este el `State`

```
context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

de esta forma si la instancia solo tiene el id porque lo usas para relacionar tomara ese valor sin afectar al resto de la entidad